# some problems about open ai gym retro

Tags: openai-gym

I have installed clang in windows system and Gym Retro by

```
pip3 install gym-retro
```

When I try to run

```
env = retro.make(game='SonicTheHedgehog-Genesis', state='GreenHillZone.Act1', record='.')
```

I got an error:

```
FileNotFoundError: Game not found: SonicTheHedgehog-Genesis. Did you make sure to import the ROM?
```

Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For openai-retro version '0.7.0' you have to access the functions using .data field.

```
import gym
import retro

for game in retro.data.list_games():
   print(game, retro.data.list_states(game))
```

Comment: But I have a problem again.